# "No data found" error during execute the procedure in oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

i have a trigger in different and want execute procedure for different schema to extract the data.

executing procedure with parameter in trigger is not working.

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGER_LEAD_INSERT
  AFTER INSERT ON AT_NEO_CM.LEAD_INFORMATION 
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  --PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN

  IF :new.LEAD_REFERENCE_NUMBER IS NOT NULL THEN    
      AT_NEO_CAS_LMS.PKG_LEAD_DATA.USP_INSERT_NEWAPP(:NEW.LEAD_REFERENCE_NUMBER,:NEW.ID );   
END IF;

  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 

       INSERT INTO LEADDATA VALUES(  :NEW.ID, :NEW.LEAD_REFERENCE_NUMBER,2322, 'NO DATA FOUND');

END TRIGER_LEAD_INSERT;
```

Using a another table in procedure with same primary key which passed in procedure as parameter.

Comment: could you please elaborate more about `executing procedure with parameter in triggre is not working.`
what exactly happens (or not happens)? What the procedure is expected to to?

Comment: Also, which version of Oracle are you using? It could affect the answer.

Comment: I have a two schema in database Test and Test1 Test has a table lead_information that trigger applied and test1 has table leaddata and im trying to insert few information in leaddata which is in another schema.  Which is not inserting and also i vahe procedure  in same test1 schema with parameter but values is not passing in this proedure due to getting error no data found in the trigger.

Comment: I'm not clear what code would raise a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception in your trigger, there is no SELECT...

Comment: Procedure has select statement  which raise exception. NO DATA FOUND for same id which pass in procedure as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a procedure from another schema, you just need to set the right grants:

```
CREATE USER u1 IDENTIFIED BY u1 QUOTA 1M ON USERS;
CREATE USER u2 IDENTIFIED BY u2 QUOTA 1M ON USERS;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO u1;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO u2;
```

User `u1` has a procedure `p1` and grants it to user `u2`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p1(p NUMBER) AS BEGIN NULL; END p1;
GRANT EXECUTE ON p1 TO u2;
```

User `u2` can now execute this procedure:

```
CONNECT u2/u2;
EXEC u1.p1(1);
```

or use it in a trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (id NUMBER);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr2 AFTER INSERT ON t2
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.id IS NOT NULL THEN    
    u1.p1(:new.id); 
  END IF; 
END tr2;
/
```

Comment: that is working. when trigger execute and extracting the data from another table its throwing error when i am going to use that id and extract the data then gets the data manually.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the error message?